# Is the in call screen on Android named differently (class name) on different phones depending on manufacturer?

Tags: android, android-activity, telephony

In emulator the activity used to show the in call screen of an incoming call is implemented in a class called "com.android.phone.InCallScreen".

Is this true on all android phones or just unmodified Android software as released by Google?

Comment: I would definitely not rely on a certain package name if i could avoid it. Seems very brittle and working/breaking by chance at best.

Comment: There is no way of starting an activity *after* the in call screen. If you read the source code which triggers your user defined broadcast handler for incoming calls you will see that Google knows this.

Comment: I mean i´d rather not make my code depend on anything that is not written in the API contracts (even those are violated now and then) if i can help it. Are you sure you can´t rework your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally different according to manufacturer package name like

```
com.<manufecturer>.phone.InCallScreen
```

If you want to check with different devices, `Hierarchy Viewer` or `Devices` tab of **Eclipse** will show `process` name when in-coming call comes